# Autocomplete in WebService using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, web-services, linq-to-sql

I am using Autocomplete using web service. And in my web service I am using LDS.

The problem is that when I am trying this code:

This is my UI code which is calling the webservice in Default.aspx:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path ="WebService1.asmx" />
    </Services>
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager> 

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
        DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServicePath ="WebService1.asmx" ServiceMethod="ReturnEntity" EnableCaching="true"  TargetControlID="TextBox1" CompletionSetCount ="1">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

This is my WebService file (webservice1.asmx)

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string[] ReturnEntity(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        List<string> responses = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            responses.Add(prefixText + (char)(i + 65));

        return responses.ToArray();
    }
```

Then is it working. However, I am working on this code and it is NOT working...

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string[] ReturnEntity(string prefixText)
    {
        using (DataClasses1DataContext search = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            string[] fullText = (from n in search.Entities
                                 where n.Name.StartsWith(prefixText)
                                 select n.Name).ToArray();

            return fullText;
        }

    }
```

When I am trying to run the webservice in the browser itself and passing some parameters then it is showing me these:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <string>Starr</string> 
  <string>Sally Jeans</string> 
  <string>Steven Kline</string> 
  <string>Steven Goldberg</string> 
  </ArrayOfString>
```

This is not returning any results. I just want to show listings from my table which is Entities, and the column name is 'Name'.

Cannot figure it out :(

Comment: Have you tried calling that method (using the DataContext) outside of using autocomplete? My best guess is that your query is not returning any results. Try using sql server profiler to determine the query your call is sending to the database, then see what happens if you execute that query in sql server management studio.

Comment: @eoldre: When viewing the web service file in the browser, I can see the results right there in an XML format. So I am assuming that it is pulling from the DB.

Comment: @DOT-NET I'm sorry, what results? If they are in the browser, what do you mean by "not returning any results"?

Comment: @Martinho: Please check out my latest edit. I posted the XML file which I'm getting if I am viewing webservice in the browser.

Comment: That is even more confusing. Your problem is not that it isn't returning any results. It is returning results (you just posted them!). What is actually your problem?

Comment: @.Net Skank - how are you querying this web service? javascript? from C#?

Comment: @Mart: My autocomplete is not working. If you run webservice then it is showing as an arraylist in the browser. But when you are running the application using Default.aspx then it is not showing the names.

Comment: Well... could you please post the code that is not working (the code that calls the webservice) then? The code you posted is working fine.

Comment: @Hunter Whore: from the UI (C#). Through ToolkitscriptManager and an AutocompleteExtender.

Comment: @Mart: I just posted the UI code from where I am calling this webservice. I think it is calling this webservice because when I running the List<string> responses = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            responses.Add(prefixText + (char)(i + 65));

        return responses.ToArray(); IT IS WORKING

Comment: /me sees `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager />`... runs away screaming

Comment: Ok, have you made sure that when you call the version using the datacontext, that you eliminate the additional "count" parameter that the other example method takes?

Comment: @eoldre: Yes Sir, I did that.

Comment: I'm not sure just what the auto complete extender does, but make sure that the method signature of the methed using DataContext matches exactly the the version that does work correctly.

Comment: Something like this: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx

Comment: @eoldre: I got it. Basically I was missing the exact type. In their documentation it is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx) and pass in a [StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx)

```
var result = from n in search.Entities
             where n.Name.StartsWith(prefixText, 
                 StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
             select n.Name;

return result.ToArray();
```

---

If this is still in the context of call you can use ToLower()

```
var result = from n in search.Entities
             where n.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(prefixText.ToLower())
             select n.Name;

return result.ToArray();
```

Comment: @.Net Dirty Whore - Things to try: Are there any results at all? Do any of them have a Name that does in fact StartWith prefixText? Is an exception being thrown? Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: @hunter: I am trying to debug this. I found out that when I am using breakpoint in ReturnEntity Function, it is being called after 3 hits in the textbox. Eg. ABC

Comment: I think you need to post your javascript

Comment: @Hunter: I just posted dude, my UI part. Please check.

Comment: @Hunter: I tried using your code above. It is showing me this error: The method 'StartsWith' has a translation to SQL, but the overload 'Boolean StartsWith(System.String, System.StringComparison)' does not.

Comment: @DOT - yeah, that would only work if you were filtering an existing collection. Since this is generating SQL it won't work because of exactly that error.